# Issue ending receipt (String) to Database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add a receipt of string type into my SQL Server database from my C# program but I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'."

and it crashes at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

This is my code in my database class:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Transaction values (@inReceipt)";

//cmd.Parameters.Add("@inDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inReceipt", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000);
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@inTotalCost", SqlDbType.Float);

//cmd.Parameters["@inDateTime"].Value = dt;
cmd.Parameters["@inReceipt"].Value = receipt;
//cmd.Parameters["@inTotalCost"].Value = totalCost;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

return cmd;
```

And my code in the form class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkoutNameArr.Length; i++)
{
    receipt += chkoutNameArr[i].ToString() + " (x" + chkoutQtyArr[i].ToString() + ") - $" + chkoutPriceArr[i] + " each\r\n" ;
}

receipt += "Discount given: " + discountPercentage + "%\r\n";
receipt += "Payment made using " + " card XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-" + txtBoxSetFour.Text;

MessageBox.Show(receipt);

db.addTransactionToDb(receipt);
```

And in my database, I have one parameter called "receipt" with VarChar(8000).

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Transaction is a reserved word in SQL

Comment: Thank you @FLICKER . It helped!

Comment: **Avoid** using one of the [reserved keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL as your table or column name - use something more meaningful to your problem domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Transaction` is a keyword in sql. Surround this with braces.

```
Insert into [dbo].[Transaction] values (@inReceipt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped!